spring-pulsar-test dependency - missing from maven centrel
This testing documentation for Spring Pulsar Testing Applications mentions a spring-pulsar-test dependency.
I have not been able to find this dependency in Maven Central and my attempts at including it in my build.gradle file like this
testImplementation "org.springframework.pulsar:spring-pulsar-test"
result in it not being found.
Is this not released?

It was first released in version 1.1.0-M2 and the latest version is 1.1.0-RC1 (here).
What version of Spring Pulsar are you using?
Are you using Spring Boot? If so, what version?

Spring  Boot is 3.2.4 and appears I have spring-pulsar 1.0.4 that comes along. I guess I am behind on that version then?

Yep, it was not introduced until 1.1.0-M2. In order pickup the newer version you can upgrade to Boot 3.3.0-RC1 or override the dependency to 1.1.0-RC1 (e.g. https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/3.3.x/gradle-plugin/reference/htmlsingle/#managing-dependencies.dependency-management-plugin.customizing). I believe you can also just specify the version directly on the test dependency as it should be compatible w/ 3.2.x.
